# Mongoose is not connecting to local database

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

This is my app.js file. Please help me out to connect it with my local database. Sometimes it gets connected to the database and logs to the console but it doesn't add any collection to the local database.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

main().catch(err=>console.log(err))

async function main() {

  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  //Creating new schema
  
  const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
  });
  
  const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
  
  const fruit = new Fruit ({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Pretty solid"
  });
  
  await fruit.save()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insist localhost use 127.0.0.1:27017 This will work for sure.

OR
This happened probably because the MongoDB service isn't started. Follow the below steps to start it:

1. Go to Control Panel and click on Administrative Tools.
2. Double-click on Services. A new window opens up.
3. Search MongoDB.exe. Right-click on it and select Start
   The server will start. Now execute npm start again and the code might work this time.

Comment: Not worked for me. I used 127.0.0.1:27017 and my mongo db service is running but still not working.

Comment: @KamranRiyaz can you provide me any error messages or additional information you receive when running the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongo connection like this in typescript for ES6.
Schema like below

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"


export const RequestLogsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    request_id: String,
    ...
  },
  {
    collection: "request_logs"
  }
)
```

example connection like below

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { RequestLogsSchema } from './mongo-schemas/RequestLogsSchema'


export class MongoClient {
  mongodb: any

  constructor(private host: string) { }

  async MongoConnect() {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, _reject): Promise<void> => {

      console.log(' MongoDB Connecting !')

      this.mongodb = await mongoose.connect(this.host).then(() => {
        console.log(' MongoDB Connected !')
        resolve(true)
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err))

    })

  }
}

export const schemas = {
  RequestLogsModal: mongoose.model("RequestLogs", RequestLogsSchema),
  ...
}

new MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/db_name?authSource=db_name').MongoConnect()
```

To save your data like

```
import { schemas } from '../connections/mongo'

const saver = (data) => {
    const request_logs = new schemas.RequestLogsModal({
      request_id: data.request_id,
      ...
    })

    await request_logs.save()
}
```